# Cocommutative k-Hopf algebra finite as k-vector space represents a constant group functor

Tags: hopf-algebras, group-schemes

I am working through some of my first exercises regarding Hopf algebras and I am kind of stuck with this one:

Given an algebraically closed field $k$ and a cocommutative $k$-Hopf algebra $A$ finite as $k$-vector space, the group functor the Hopf algebra represents is constant. As you can notice I am looking at an entirely algebraic approach, not using scheme theory language. Here's what I know:

I proved that the tangent space $T_0A \cong Hom_{k-HopfAlg}(k[X],A^\vee)$, where $k[X]$ represents $\mathbb{G}_{a,k}$, and $A^\vee$ is the dual Hopf algebra i.e. the one representing the Cartier dual of the functor $h^A(-)$ . Also proved: $A$ represents a constant group functor iff $A^0 \cong k$, where $A^0$ is the "connected part" in the canonical decomposition $A \cong A^0 \otimes A^{const}$. I hope that it is clear what I mean by this notation. I realise that it is a bit strange to talk about this without using group scheme theory, but my course is structured in that manner.

I hope it's not too impolite to ask that any hints and/or answers be detailed about what they are trying to get across, since, as I mentioned, I don't have a lot of intuition on this. My main problem is not having enough time to go through a Group Scheme Theory textbook before I have to turn in my homework.

Comment: What is $A^\vee$?

Comment: What happens with the Hopf algebra $k[x]/(x^p)$ (with $k$ of characteristic $p$) (or its dual, depending on how you are doing things)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I added that $A^\vee$ is the dual of $A$. I am not sure about what you mean by your second question. What happens is that since it is local $A \cong A^0 \not\cong k$, obviously it is not constant. But how does that help prove that if it is cocommutative and finite it is constant?

Comment: Well, my A is a finite dimensional commutative and cocommutative Hopf algebra over an algebraicly closed field which does not give a constant group scheme.

Comment: On the other hand, over a field of characteristic zero, a finitely generated Hopf algebra is reduced, so if it is finite dimensional it is (as an algebra) a finite direct product of finite extensions of the ground field, and if the ground field is moreover algebraically closed, then etc.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I understand, so it is only true in char 0, I'll correct the question. However, I would have to prove that for a field of characteristic zero a finitely generated Hopf algebra is reduced, since I don't have that result (that's Cartier's theorem right?). However, the assumption is that it is finite as a k-vector space, i.e. finite not only finitely generated algebra, so I assumed that this would simplify things somewhat.